# Link MKL to an installed Numpy in Anaconda?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, blas, intel-mkl

```
>>> numpy.__config__.show()
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/admin/anaconda/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = c
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/admin/anaconda/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = f77
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/admin/anaconda/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = f77
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
    libraries = ['f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/admin/anaconda/lib']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    language = c
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

This is numpy.**config**.show()

And this numpy is based on Anaconda.

in /home/admin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy

And meanwhile, I have installed MKL in /opt/intel/mkl.

**Also it seems that, I can use MKL, when I used Theano with this Anaconda and this numpy.**

Thank you~

Comment: Are you a student at a recognized university? If so, register for an academic license [here](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/academicanaconda) and `conda install accelerate`.

Comment: Yep, the only way to link against a different BLAS/LAPACK is to recompile or get a different binary. An Anaconda academic license lets you get a faster binary. Compiling numpy from source isn't terribly hard either though.

Comment: @jme  Thank you for you answer. Yes,  I'm a student. But it seems that, I can use MKL, when I used Theano with this Anaconda and this numpy. Is Theano not based on Numpy?

Comment: @IanH Thank you for you answer. But it seems that, I can use MKL, when I used Theano with this Anaconda and this numpy. Is Theano not based on Numpy?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll have to get the [Numpy source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) and create a `site.cfg` file in the main folder that tells Numpy where to look for the MKL libraries. Use the `site.cfg.example` file as a guide; there's a section in there on MKL that should tell you the exact lines you need.

Once you have a `site.cfg` file, run `python setup.py config`. This will spit out the configuration info (it looks like the output of `numpy.config.show()`). You should see the paths to your MKL libraries in there (if not, you'll have to play around with the `site.cfg` file until you do).

Then, you can build and install with `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`. You may want to uninstall your old Numpy first.

I have a blog post on [installing Numpy with OpenBLAS](https://hunseblog.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/installing-numpy-and-openblas/). While your situation is a little different, a lot of steps are similar I think.