# Default numpy vs accelerate in Anaconda

Tags: numpy, anaconda, intel-mkl

I have just installed numpy-1.10.1 through Anaconda in a Python 2.7.10 environment, in Windows. To my surprise, I discovered that it has MKL out-of-the-box (see the config below). I ran [a benchmark](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/6/7/1/0/5/41177-Examples.py) against a "manual" Python 2.7.10 install with numpy+mkl-1.10.1 from [Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), and they show the same figures. And the config is identical.

I am wondering what does Anaconda accelerate package bring for numpy then?

Anaconda numpy-1.10.1 config

```
>>> np.__config__.show()
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd', 'mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd', 'mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
```

(Interestingly, [Link MKL to an installed Numpy in Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392390/link-mkl-to-an-installed-numpy-in-anaconda) reports a different configuration.)

Gohlke numpy-1.10.1+mkl config

```
>>> np.__config__.show()
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd', 'mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd', 'mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
```

Comment: You mean this? http://docs.continuum.io/accelerate/index  --- the documentation on the page probably explains what it does.

Comment: @pv. I am interested in numpy only. The page you refer to says that accelerate includes numpy with MKL. But what I see is that even without accelerate numpy in Anaconda comes with MKL. I am going to run benchmarks with accelerate free trial to figure out, unless someone explains it earlier here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the benchmarking script linked in the question, I can see that numpy in accelerate and just numpy in Anaconda provide the same performance.

[image: Numpy with accelerate vs numpy in Anaconda]

Comparison was done under Python 2.7.10 64-bit on i7-4790K @ 4 GHz with 32GB RAM. Since accelerate currently downgrades numpy to 1.9.3, I compared it against numpy 1.9.3, and numpy 1.10.1 for reference.

I conclude that when using only numpy, accelerate does not bring additional performance.

For completeness, here is config of numpy-1.9.3 in accelerate:

```
>>> np.__config__.show()
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\include']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\include']
mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\libs']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\aroot\\stage\\include']
```